# Drop duplicate rows in python vaex

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

I am working with python vaex, and I don't know how I can drop duplicate rows in a dataframe. For example in pandas there exists the method `drop_duplicates()`. Does there exist any similar function in vaex?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is none yet, but we should expect this functionality at some point.

In the meantime, there is [an attempt from the creator of vaex](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/746)

Answer (score 1):

I went with this `groupby` approach:

```
import vaex
df = vaex.from_arrays(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                      s=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'A', 'b', 'c', 'D'],
                      q=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
df['new'] = df.x
dfg = df.groupby(['x', 's', 'q']).agg({'new': "sum"})['x', 's', 'q']
dfg
```

So basically you add some sort of numeric column and then group over the original columns and sum on the new column and then just get rid of the new sum; leaving the unique (grouped) list of original columns.

Comment: This works, but keep in mind that the output is in memory. If your group-by output is too big to fit in ram, this approach will not work.

Comment: Surely `vaex` does out of core, so too big to fit in ram is not an issue?

Comment: It does, and the groupby aggregation is out of care also, but the resulting dataframe is in memory. So just be careful when doing groupbys with lots of columns